Exploring Effective Methods for Splitting Mixed Value Types in Datasets
Good Morning Community,
I have many existing datasets following a variation of  this format:



NAME
TIME
Speed1
Speed2
Speed3




LAZER
21:29:30
F350
F350
F350


PIREX
21:35:40
F350
F350
F350


MANGA07103223:25:29
M085
F350
F350
F350


ATSUR
23:30:30
F360
F360
F360


GIGBL
24:10:30
F360
F360
F360


RIVAK
25:25:10
F370
F370
F370


ATY22102511:41:46
N0465
F390
F390
F390



There are instances that under the NAME value, the NAME follows 6 numerical values followed by time. I would like the time value to be split in order to shift the rows and re-aligning the values to their respective columns.  So in essence it looks like this:



NAME
TIME
Speed1
Speed2
Speed3




LAZER
21:29:30
F350
F350
F350


PIREX
21:35:40
F350
F350
F350


MANGA071032
23:25:29
M085
F350
F350


ATSUR
23:30:30
F360
F360
F360


GIGBL
24:10:30
F360
F360
F360


RIVAK
25:25:10
F370
F370
F370


ATY221025
11:41:46
N0465
F390
F390



I have to apologize but in past history, i've tried to provide my attempts but for this particular case, I need help from the community, whether it's to provide me literature for me to attempt to create a script or some minor examples but I would like to use Pandas and I was thinking of using Regular Expressions could be used in this case.
The tricky part (to me) and what I do know is to account for the values in the NAME column which will always change and the text characters could be two characters, three, four not to exceed 5 characters max (e.g. MANGA, ATY, BG, ANNA, etc) and these names will change.
Additionally, the numerical characters that are in between the values in name and time are ALWAYS 6 numbers (this is the location of the name) e.g. MANGA071032  ATY221025
I hope this makes sense and thank you again to everyone.

given your data this regex
([A-Z]{2,5}\d{6})(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})

should be able to split your text and timestamp
a slight modification in case you can have the timestamp in the wrong place but no other digits in the name would be
([a-z]{2,5}(?:\d{6})?)(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})

group 1 would be your name, group 2 your timestamp
i just would like to ask how you load your data is it also wrong in the source?

Thank you for your help! I have not tried to implement this yet (I will shortly after this response)  but I wanted to answer this.  This is a .dat file that I am provided  from a system that records transportation data.  I then take this file and go through a series of logic to filter it and transform it into a dataframe so that it can be easily read/fed for data analysis purposes. The short answer is that it is wrong in the source but I have no control over changing it at the source/system level. Did I answer your question? :)

I meant to add that this didn't seem to quite work. The first example seemed to remove the entire MANTA example but still left other fixes. But I will try to work with this. Thank you very much
